# seperation of foldername and display in to column using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hy, I'm new in VBA,
I need some example of code VBA for get list of subfolders with specified name to put in excel table. Name of my folder is like:
AUD_C1234_02_PRODUCTS

I want to get names like this (each folder names in new row) in to table that I have 4 columns, so separator for new columns is underscore _
Final result must be:
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
AUD C1234 02 PRODUCTS

Answer (score 1):

1. Getting the subfolders:
   You could create the FileSysteScripting object.
2. Separate the folder names into 4 columns.
   You could use the split() function to do so.

Here are the sample codes:

```
Sub putSubFoldersIntoSheet(inputFolderPath As String)

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    Dim inputFolder As Folder
    Set inputFolder = fso.GetFolder(inputFolderPath)

    Dim subFolder As Folder

    Dim rowIndex As Long: rowIndex = 1
    Dim columnIndex As Long: columnIndex = 1

    For Each subFolder In inputFolder.SubFolders

        Dim folderName As String
        folderName = subFolder.Name

        Dim splitFolderName() As String
        splitFolderName = Split(folderName, "_")

        Dim splitFolderNameElement As Variant

        columnIndex = 1
        For Each splitFolderNameElement In splitFolderName

            Sheet1.Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex) = splitFolderNameElement
            columnIndex = columnIndex + 1
        Next

        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi... thnx for helping ...but while running in macros it is not choosing the folder .............

Comment: can u tell me what to do so??

Comment: To invoke this function, you need to pass in the folder path as the parameter.